# Strip out special characters

Tags: php

I pull some data from a HTML page with a list of products and for some text it looks like this:

> Organicâ„¢

In the HTML page when I look at that same text I can see its supposed to read Organic with the TM (Trade Mark) symbol after it. Why does it look like the above!

My main question is How can I get rid of TM, @ and Copyright symbols so I am just left with a clean name of the product?

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page has the wrong character set declared (or no character set declared at all).

View the source HTML and see if in the `head` section there is a tag like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

If there's no such tag, or the tag is there but the `charset` bit is missing, you haven't declared a character set. If the tag is there and the `charset` bit is present, the declared character set is wrong. Looking at the specific example you gave, it looks like the text might be in UTF-8 but is being displayed as latin-1.

Comment: The web server itself can also declare the character set in the HTTP `Content-Type` tag (hence why the `http-equiv="Content-Type"`)

Answer (score 0):

It's an encoding issue ; there's a gap between your html page encoding, and your output device encoding.

You'll have to rationalize this. The best is to have your working environment in utf8, and to convert all external data into utf8.

Comment: That is what I thought of at first. I actually tried a utf_decode and the last few characters turned into a single `?`. Maybe I can rely on this and just strip out the question mark?

Comment: You don't need decoding but encoding. Decoding would just make you go from utf8 to unicode (for example).